# How to generate a random Time?

Tags: random, time, crystal-lang

How to generate a random `Time`, say, in between `Time::UNIX_EPOCH` and `Time.local`?

I need it to shuffle an array, which being sorted by `Time` field afterwards.

Comment: If you don't care about time zones - which seems to be the case since you don't care about specific time values anyways - you should use `Time.utc` instead of `Time.local`. It's marginally faster and better expresses intent.

Comment: @JohannesMüller, thank you, that's a great point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Time.unix(Random.new.rand(Time::UNIX_EPOCH.to_unix..Time.local.to_unix))
```

https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/8g06

Comment: That's very elegant, thank you. Might be even shorter: `Time.unix(rand(Time::UNIX_EPOCH.to_unix..Time.local.to_unix))`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use a fixed time (for example `UNIX_EPOCH`) and add a random time span.

```
Time::UNIX_EPOCH.shift seconds: rand(1_000_000_000)
```